# Anaconda Navigator unable to launch Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to open Anaconda Navigator, whenever I try to open it nothing will happen. I have tried to reinstalling anaconda navigator and also tried updating conda through anaconda prompt. I have also tried restarting my computer multiple times.

I have also tried installing it in another HDD.

I am able to launch it by using anaconda-navigator but it gets stuck at loading applications.

i have tried this :
Try change the file at anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py at line 1364 from data = yaml.load(f) to data = yaml.safeload(f)

It loads the navigator but when I try to launch Jupyter notebook this error shows up:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in  from
>   notebook.notebookapp import main File
>   "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py",
>   line 47, in  from zmq.eventloop import ioloop File
>   "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq__init__.py",
>   line 47, in  from zmq import backend File
>   "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py",
>   line 40, in  reraise(*exc_info) File
>   "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py",
>   line 34, in reraise raise value File
>   "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py",
>   line 27, in 
>   _ns = select_backend(first) File "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py",
>   line 28, in select_backend mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py",
>   line 6, in  from . import (constants, error, message, context,
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython'
>   (C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py)

The conda info and conda list output is given below, please help.

Thank you!

CONDA info in ANACONDA PROMPT

> C:\Users\gordo>conda info
>
> ```
>  active environment : None
>    user config file : C:\Users\gordo\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\gordo\.condarc
>       conda version : 4.7.10
> conda-build version : 3.18.8
>      python version : 3.7.3.final.0
>    virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
>    base environment : D:\Anaconda  (writable)
>        channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>       package cache : D:\Anaconda\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\gordo\.conda\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
>    envs directories : D:\Anaconda\envs
>                       C:\Users\gordo\.conda\envs
>                       C:\Users\gordo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
>            platform : win-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
>       administrator : False
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False
> ```

CONDA LIST in ANACONDA PROMPT

> ```
> C:\Users\gordo>    conda list --show-channel-urls
> # packages in environment at D:\Anaconda:
> #
> # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
> _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults alabaster   0.7.12      py37_0    defaults
> anaconda                  2019.07                  py37_0    defaults
> anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0    defaults
> anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0    defaults
> anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0    defaults
> asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0    defaults
> astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0    defaults
> astropy                   3.2.1            py37he774522_0    defaults
> atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1    defaults
> attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1    defaults
> babel                     2.7.0                      py_0    defaults
> backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
> backports                 1.0                        py_2    defaults
> backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2   
> defaults backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0   
> defaults backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                   
> py37_2    defaults backports.tempfile        1.0                      
> py_1    defaults backports.weakref         1.0.post1                 
> py_1    defaults beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                   
> py37_1    defaults bitarray                  0.9.3           
> py37he774522_0    defaults bkcharts                  0.2              
> py37_0    defaults blas                      1.0                      
> mkl    defaults bleach                    3.1.0                   
> py37_0    defaults blosc                     1.16.3              
> h7bd577a_0    defaults bokeh                     1.2.0                
> py37_0    defaults boto                      2.49.0                  
> py37_0    defaults bottleneck                1.2.1           
> py37h452e1ab_1    defaults bzip2                     1.0.8            
> he774522_0    defaults ca-certificates           2019.5.15            
> 0    defaults certifi                   2019.6.16               
> py37_0    defaults cffi                      1.12.3          
> py37h7a1dbc1_0    defaults chardet                   3.0.4            
> py37_1    defaults click                     7.0                     
> py37_0    defaults cloudpickle               1.2.1                    
> py_0    defaults clyent                    1.2.2                   
> py37_1    defaults colorama                  0.4.1                   
> py37_0    defaults comtypes                  1.1.7                   
> py37_0    defaults conda                     4.7.10                  
> py37_0    defaults conda-build               3.18.8                  
> py37_0    defaults conda-env                 2.6.0                    
> 1    defaults conda-package-handling    1.3.11                  
> py37_0    defaults conda-verify              3.4.2                    
> py_1    defaults console_shortcut          0.1.1                      
> 3    defaults contextlib2               0.5.5                   
> py37_0    defaults cryptography              2.7             
> py37h7a1dbc1_0    defaults curl                      7.65.2           
> h2a8f88b_0    defaults cycler                    0.10.0               
> py37_0    defaults cython                    0.29.12         
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults cytoolz                   0.10.0          
> py37he774522_0    defaults dask                      2.1.0            
> py_0    defaults dask-core                 2.1.0                     
> py_0    defaults decorator                 4.4.0                   
> py37_1    defaults defusedxml                0.6.0                    
> py_0    defaults distributed               2.1.0                     
> py_0    defaults docutils                  0.14                    
> py37_0    defaults entrypoints               0.3                     
> py37_0    defaults et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   
> py37_0    defaults fastcache                 1.1.0           
> py37he774522_0    defaults filelock                  3.0.12           
> py_0    defaults flask                     1.1.1                     
> py_0    defaults freetype                  2.9.1               
> ha9979f8_1    defaults future                    0.17.1               
> py37_0    defaults get_terminal_size         1.0.0               
> h38e98db_0    defaults gevent                    1.4.0           
> py37he774522_0    defaults glob2                     0.7              
> py_0    defaults greenlet                  0.4.15          
> py37hfa6e2cd_0    defaults h5py                      2.9.0           
> py37h5e291fa_0    defaults hdf5                      1.10.4           
> h7ebc959_0    defaults heapdict                  1.0.0                
> py37_2    defaults html5lib                  1.0.1                   
> py37_0    defaults icc_rt                    2019.0.0            
> h0cc432a_1    defaults icu                       58.2                
> ha66f8fd_1    defaults idna                      2.8                  
> py37_0    defaults imageio                   2.5.0                   
> py37_0    defaults imagesize                 1.1.0                   
> py37_0    defaults importlib_metadata        0.17                    
> py37_1    defaults intel-openmp              2019.4                   
> 245    defaults ipykernel                 5.1.1           
> py37h39e3cac_0    defaults ipython                   7.6.1           
> py37h39e3cac_0    defaults ipython_genutils          0.2.0            
> py37_0    defaults ipywidgets                7.5.0                    
> py_0    defaults isort                     4.3.21                  
> py37_0    defaults itsdangerous              1.1.0                   
> py37_0    defaults jdcal                     1.4.1                    
> py_0    defaults jedi                      0.13.3                  
> py37_0    defaults jinja2                    2.10.1                  
> py37_0    defaults joblib                    0.13.2                  
> py37_0    defaults jpeg                      9b                  
> hb83a4c4_2    defaults json5                     0.8.4                
> py_0    defaults jsonschema                3.0.1                   
> py37_0    defaults jupyter                   1.0.0                   
> py37_7    defaults jupyter_client            5.3.1                    
> py_0    defaults jupyter_console           6.0.0                   
> py37_0    defaults jupyter_core              4.5.0                    
> py_0    defaults jupyterlab                1.0.2           
> py37hf63ae98_0    defaults jupyterlab_server         1.0.0            
> py_0    defaults keyring                   18.0.0                  
> py37_0    defaults kiwisolver                1.1.0           
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults krb5                      1.16.1           
> hc04afaa_7    defaults lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1           
> py37he774522_0    defaults libarchive                3.3.3            
> h0643e63_5    defaults libcurl                   7.65.2              
> h2a8f88b_0    defaults libiconv                  1.15                
> h1df5818_7    defaults liblief                   0.9.0               
> ha925a31_2    defaults libpng                    1.6.37              
> h2a8f88b_0    defaults libsodium                 1.0.16              
> h9d3ae62_0    defaults libssh2                   1.8.2               
> h7a1dbc1_0    defaults libtiff                   4.0.10              
> hb898794_2    defaults libxml2                   2.9.9               
> h464c3ec_0    defaults libxslt                   1.1.33              
> h579f668_0    defaults llvmlite                  0.29.0          
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults locket                    0.2.0            
> py37_1    defaults lxml                      4.3.4           
> py37h1350720_0    defaults lz4-c                     1.8.1.2          
> h2fa13f4_0    defaults lzo                       2.10                
> h6df0209_2    defaults m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                
> 6    defaults m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                        
> 7    defaults m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                        
> 7    defaults m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                        
> 2    defaults m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757            
> 2    defaults markupsafe                1.1.1           
> py37he774522_0    defaults matplotlib                3.1.0           
> py37hc8f65d3_0    defaults mccabe                    0.6.1            
> py37_1    defaults menuinst                  1.4.16          
> py37he774522_0    defaults mistune                   0.8.4           
> py37he774522_0    defaults mkl                       2019.4           
> 245    defaults mkl-service               2.0.2           
> py37he774522_0    defaults mkl_fft                   1.0.12          
> py37h14836fe_0    defaults mkl_random                1.0.2           
> py37h343c172_0    defaults mock                      3.0.5            
> py37_0    defaults more-itertools            7.0.0                   
> py37_0    defaults mpmath                    1.1.0                   
> py37_0    defaults msgpack-python            0.6.1           
> py37h74a9793_1    defaults msys2-conda-epoch         20160418         
> 1    defaults multipledispatch          0.6.0                   
> py37_0    defaults navigator-updater         0.2.1                   
> py37_0    defaults nbconvert                 5.5.0                    
> py_0    defaults nbformat                  4.4.0                   
> py37_0    defaults networkx                  2.3                      
> py_0    defaults nltk                      3.4.4                   
> py37_0    defaults nose                      1.3.7                   
> py37_2    defaults notebook                  6.0.0                   
> py37_0    defaults numba                     0.44.1          
> py37hf9181ef_0    defaults numexpr                   2.6.9           
> py37hdce8814_0    defaults numpy                     1.16.4          
> py37h19fb1c0_0    defaults numpy-base                1.16.4          
> py37hc3f5095_0    defaults numpydoc                  0.9.1            
> py_0    defaults olefile                   0.46                    
> py37_0    defaults openpyxl                  2.6.2                    
> py_0    defaults openssl                   1.1.1c              
> he774522_1    defaults packaging                 19.0                 
> py37_0    defaults pandas                    0.24.2          
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults pandoc                    2.2.3.2          
> 0    defaults pandocfilters             1.4.2                   
> py37_1    defaults parso                     0.5.0                    
> py_0    defaults partd                     1.0.0                     
> py_0    defaults path.py                   12.0.1                    
> py_0    defaults pathlib2                  2.3.4                   
> py37_0    defaults patsy                     0.5.1                   
> py37_0    defaults pep8                      1.7.1                   
> py37_0    defaults pickleshare               0.7.5                   
> py37_0    defaults pillow                    6.1.0           
> py37hdc69c19_0    defaults pip                       19.1.1           
> py37_0    defaults pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                 
> py37_0    defaults pluggy                    0.12.0                   
> py_0    defaults ply                       3.11                    
> py37_0    defaults powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                    
> 2    defaults prometheus_client         0.7.1                     
> py_0    defaults prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                   
> py37_0    defaults psutil                    5.6.3           
> py37he774522_0    defaults py                        1.8.0            
> py37_0    defaults py-lief                   0.9.0           
> py37ha925a31_2    defaults pycodestyle               2.5.0            
> py37_0    defaults pycosat                   0.6.3           
> py37hfa6e2cd_0    defaults pycparser                 2.19             
> py37_0    defaults pycrypto                  2.6.1           
> py37hfa6e2cd_9    defaults pycurl                    7.43.0.3        
> py37h7a1dbc1_0    defaults pyflakes                  2.1.1            
> py37_0    defaults pygments                  2.4.2                    
> py_0    defaults pylint                    2.3.1                   
> py37_0    defaults pyodbc                    4.0.26          
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults pyopenssl                 19.0.0           
> py37_0    defaults pyparsing                 2.4.0                    
> py_0    defaults pyqt                      5.9.2           
> py37h6538335_2    defaults pyreadline                2.1              
> py37_1    defaults pyrsistent                0.14.11         
> py37he774522_0    defaults pysocks                   1.7.0            
> py37_0    defaults pytables                  3.5.2           
> py37h1da0976_1    defaults pytest                    5.0.1            
> py37_0    defaults pytest-arraydiff          0.3             
> py37h39e3cac_0    defaults pytest-astropy            0.5.0            
> py37_0    defaults pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                   
> py37_0    defaults pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                   
> py37_0    defaults pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                   
> py37_0    defaults python                    3.7.3               
> h8c8aaf0_1    defaults python-dateutil           2.8.0                
> py37_0    defaults python-libarchive-c       2.8                    
> py37_11    defaults pytz                      2019.1                  
> py_0    defaults pywavelets                1.0.3           
> py37h8c2d366_1    defaults pywin32                   223             
> py37hfa6e2cd_1    defaults pywinpty                  0.5.5            
> py37_1000    defaults pyyaml                    5.1.1           
> py37he774522_0    defaults pyzmq                     18.0.0          
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults qt                        5.9.7           
> vc14h73c81de_0    defaults qtawesome                 0.5.7            
> py37_1    defaults qtconsole                 4.5.1                    
> py_0    defaults qtpy                      1.8.0                     
> py_0    defaults requests                  2.22.0                  
> py37_0    defaults rope                      0.14.0                   
> py_0    defaults ruamel_yaml               0.15.46         
> py37hfa6e2cd_0    defaults scikit-image              0.15.0          
> py37ha925a31_0    defaults scikit-learn              0.21.2          
> py37h6288b17_0    defaults scipy                     1.2.1           
> py37h29ff71c_0    defaults seaborn                   0.9.0            
> py37_0    defaults send2trash                1.5.0                   
> py37_0    defaults setuptools                41.0.1                  
> py37_0    defaults simplegeneric             0.8.1                   
> py37_2    defaults singledispatch            3.4.0.3                 
> py37_0    defaults sip                       4.19.8          
> py37h6538335_0    defaults six                       1.12.0           
> py37_0    defaults snappy                    1.1.7               
> h777316e_3    defaults snowballstemmer           1.9.0                
> py_0    defaults sortedcollections         1.1.2                   
> py37_0    defaults sortedcontainers          2.1.0                   
> py37_0    defaults soupsieve                 1.8                     
> py37_0    defaults sphinx                    2.1.2                    
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib             1.0                     
> py37_1    defaults sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                    
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                  
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                     
> py_0    defaults spyder                    3.3.6                   
> py37_0    defaults spyder-kernels            0.5.1                   
> py37_0    defaults sqlalchemy                1.3.5           
> py37he774522_0    defaults sqlite                    3.29.0           
> he774522_0    defaults statsmodels               0.10.0          
> py37h8c2d366_0    defaults sympy                     1.4              
> py37_0    defaults tblib                     1.4.0                    
> py_0    defaults terminado                 0.8.2                   
> py37_0    defaults testpath                  0.4.2                   
> py37_0    defaults tk                        8.6.8               
> hfa6e2cd_0    defaults toolz                     0.10.0               
> py_0    defaults tornado                   6.0.3           
> py37he774522_0    defaults tqdm                      4.32.1           
> py_0    defaults traitlets                 4.3.2                   
> py37_0    defaults unicodecsv                0.14.1                  
> py37_0    defaults urllib3                   1.24.2                  
> py37_0    defaults vc                        14.1                
> h0510ff6_4    defaults vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706         
> h3a45250_4    defaults wcwidth                   0.1.7                
> py37_0    defaults webencodings              0.5.1                   
> py37_1    defaults werkzeug                  0.15.4                   
> py_0    defaults wheel                     0.33.4                  
> py37_0    defaults widgetsnbextension        3.5.0                   
> py37_0    defaults win_inet_pton             1.1.0                   
> py37_0    defaults win_unicode_console       0.5                     
> py37_0    defaults wincertstore              0.2                     
> py37_0    defaults winpty                    0.4.3                    
> 4    defaults wrapt                     1.11.2          
> py37he774522_0    defaults xlrd                      1.2.0            
> py37_0    defaults xlsxwriter                1.1.8                    
> py_0    defaults xlwings                   0.15.8                  
> py37_0    defaults xlwt                      1.3.0                   
> py37_0    defaults xz                        5.2.4               
> h2fa13f4_4    defaults yaml                      0.1.7               
> hc54c509_2    defaults zeromq                    4.3.1               
> h33f27b4_3    defaults zict                      1.0.0                
> py_0    defaults zipp                      0.5.1                     
> py_0    defaults zlib                      1.2.11              
> h62dcd97_3    defaults zstd                      1.3.7               
> h508b16e_0    defaults
> ```